# How to prove that a subset is discrete?

Tags: general-topology

Please help me to prove that if $F$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x,y\in F$ implies that $x-y\in F$, then $F$ is discrete iff $\alpha=\inf\lbrace x\in F:x>0 \rbrace$>0 and in that case $F=\alpha\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\alpha >0$. First prove that $\alpha\in F$. Use that $F$ is closed. Then, using that, pick $f\in F$ and look at $$n=\left\lfloor \frac{f}{\alpha}\right\rfloor$$

For the converse, suppose that $\alpha=0$ and show $F$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. To do it, take $x\in\Bbb R$ and $0<f<\varepsilon$, then again look at $$n'=\left\lfloor \frac x f\right\rfloor$$ and see where if fits in an $\varepsilon$ neighborhodd of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not actually necessary to assume that $F$ is closed.

The main hypothesis is that $F-F\subseteq F$, where for $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R$ we let $$A-B=\{a-b:a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}\;.$$ Clearly $0\in F-F$, so for each $x\in F$ we have $x=x-0\in F$, and hence $F-F=F$. Moreover, for each $x\in F$ we have $-x=0-x\in F$, so $F=-F$. Finally, for any $x,y\in F$ we have $x+y=x-(-y)\in F$, so $F$ is a subgroup of the additive group of real numbers. (If you’re not familiar with groups, just say that $F$ is closed under addition and taking negatives.)

Now let $\alpha=\inf\{x\in F:x>0\}$, and suppose that $\alpha>0$. Suppose that there are $x,y\in F$ such that $0<|x-y|<\alpha$. Without loss of generality assume that $x>y$, and let $\epsilon=x-y$. Then $\epsilon\in F$, but $0<\epsilon<\alpha$, contradicting the definition of $\alpha$. Thus, $|x-y|\ge\alpha$ whenever $x$ and $y$ are distinct points of $F$.

Now let $\epsilon=\frac{\alpha}2$; it follows easily from the previous paragraph that for each $x\in\Bbb R$ the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ contains at most one point of $F$ and hence that $F$ is closed and discrete.

Conversely, if $F$ is discrete, then there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\cap F=\{x\}$ for each $x\in F$, and it follows immediately that $\alpha\ge\epsilon>0$, and (as above) $F$ is also closed.

To summarize, $F$ is closed and discrete if and only if $\alpha>0$. If this is the case, $\alpha\in F$: on the one hand the interval $[\alpha,\alpha+\epsilon)$ contains points of $F$ arbitrarily close to $\alpha$, but on the other hand the interval $(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)$ contains at most one point of $F$. Since $F$ is a group under addition, $F\supseteq\Bbb Z\alpha$. Suppose that $x\in F\setminus\Bbb Z\alpha$; there is a unique $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $n\alpha<x<(n+1)\alpha$. Let $y=x-n\alpha$; then $y\in F$, and $0<y<\alpha$, which is impossible. Thus, $F=\Bbb Z\alpha$.